# What image dimensions are used for 500px?

Tags: web, resolution, 500px

The name is [500px.com](http://500px.com/), but what is the image resolution for which to optimize before uploading your photos there?

Comment: is it not 500 pixels? I thought that was whole point ;)

Comment: I myself am struggeling with 500px. All my super fine sharp photographs turn out horrible. Tried everything, 900px tall or 880px wide. Now im uploading a 20mb photo to see if it makes a difference. But i get such crappy quality, this isnt fun anymore!! @Hasin, thank you so much. Gonna try it right away!! Edit: didnt improve much. Maybe a tiny bit.. But the quality on flickr is really good btw :D

Comment: I use a trick here. I upload my photos to Flickr first and download the large version of my photo from flickr which is 1024 pixel in either side. And then I upload it to 500px. May sound funny but it retains the sharpness. Give it a try.

Comment: I don't have an answer here, but I'd be careful that whatever the answer is today, it may not be tomorrow.  They're still changing their code base pretty rapidly, including the recent releases that introduced their "flow" view and the market stuff.  I'd expect more changes to come for a while, at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Photos are displayed at 2048px on their longest edge. Have a read on [500px support page](https://support.500px.com/hc/en-us/articles/204700127-How-do-I-upload-photos-) for more details.

Comment: One would imagine it was 500px!

Answer (score 8):

From their [relevant Support page](http://support.500px.com/customer/portal/articles/361123-photo-size-parameters): width 880px for photos in landscape orientation, height 900px for images in portrait orientation. Even when you submit your images in that size, they will still get resized for display in thumbnails, and on iOS devices. Oh, and your carefully prepared originals in correct size [are still recompressed](https://getsatisfaction.com/500px/topics/pic_size-3a37m) into smaller files.

[The name is a leftover](http://500px.com/about) from early days of digital photography, when 500 pixels was a suitable size for longer edge of images distributed over slower-than-today connections and displayed on CRT monitors.

Answer (score 0):

Today i figured out why my photos looked like crap. It has something to do with either the time of day you are visiting: every photo will be shown in uber compressed format on certain busy times of the day, or it has to do with how fast your own internet connection is.

I just checked in on 500px, all pictures provide outstanding quality. When I switched back to my satellite internet connection (which has a crappy connection during daytime), everything turned crap again.

so there you have it.

Comment: Are you sure your satellite Internet provider isn't doing something to intercept and compress the images?